# Nested list from String

Tags: python

I was searching a long time on stackoverflow - but nothing helped.

OK, i have extracted a string, wich looks like this:

```
e = ['[23,99.3],[1,99.6],[3,99.5]']
```

When i say e[0] is becomes a very nice array of lists

```
e = e[0]
e= [23,99.3],[1,99.6],[3,99.5]
```

But when i now try to access the data it only splits into numbers/chars.
like this:

```
[
2
3
...
```

I tried yet:
enumerate, ast, for loops and many things more - think ast might be a cool solution but not sure yet.

Thanks

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: `e` is a list of length 1 that contains _one_ string - thate vaguely looks like a `repr([[23,99.3],[1,99.6],[3,99.5]])` ...

Answer (score -1):

If you have: `e = ['[23,99.3],[1,99.6],[3,99.5]']` is not a list of lists. Is a single string inside a one length list.

`e[0]` is the string, so when you slice over the string you get the single characters.

**EDIT**

Wrong sentence removed, please refer to the duplicate question to know how to split the string in a list.

Comment: `e[0].split(',')` give ``["[23", "99.3]", "[1", ...]`` and it's not the excepted output

Comment: Your split wont give him the list he looks for .. it returs a list of strings that look like a mangled version of the inner lists string representation ...

Comment: You're right! I did not consider the commas inside the square brackets! Shame on me.

Comment: i found this - but it did not helped my ...